# I have an issue with apps script when I insert the image in spreadsheet and then convert it to pdf. The image doesn't appear in the document pdf

Tags: google-apps-script

I have a problem with my script, when I convert the data from the spreadsheet to pdf, the image of the qr code is not converted and the space is blank,

a spreadsheet with the script is at this link:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1BOPQHx7vd5eMbBZIhMwQpdAW0ZkYI9H0qPJjFIsP7Lk/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Although I'm not sure whether I could correctly your question, it seems that your Spreadsheet can be converted to PDF file including the image of the qr code. For example, if you want to use a script, how about trying this script? ``DriveApp.createFile(DriveApp.getFileById("1BOPQHx7vd5eMbBZIhMwQpdAW0ZkYI9H0qPJjFIsP7Lk").getBlob())``

Comment: Hello, thank you, I continue with the memo problem, I need to send the images based on a template, and the images remain blank. I'm doing it this way:
// Create the PDF file 
      copyDoc.saveAndClose()
      var newFile =DriveApp.createFile(copyFile.getAs('application/pdf'))  
      copyFile.setTrashed(true)

Comment: Thank you for replying. In order to correctly understand your situation, can you provide your current script for replicating your issue? By this, I would like to think of about your solution. Unfortunately, I couldn't understand about your issue from your script in your reply. I apologize for my poor skill. If you can do, please add it to your question by the editing button.

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

```
function makePdf() {
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var shts=ss.getSheets();
  var sheetName='Base de dados';
  for(var i=0;i<shts.length;i++) {
    if(shts[i].getName()!=sheetName) {
      shts[i].hideSheet();
    }
  }
  var folder=DriveApp.getFolderById('FolderId');
  var blob=ss.getBlob();
  var file=folder.createFile(blob).getAs('application/pdf');
}
```

Comment: Thank you, in this way, the whole worksheet is exported, but how can I send the qr code images inside the invoice template?

Comment: What's the invoice template?